# How to use Apache HTTPClient's post method to send a List to the server

Tags: java, http, apache-commons-httpclient

I wish to append a `List<Beans>` in a HTTP Post request.

While making use of Apache `HTTPClient`, I am unable to do the same.

This is what I wish to do:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dailySalesList",beanList));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

However, the BasicNameValuePair seems to take only 2 Strings as argument. I wish to utilize it so that I can use a String - for identification and Object - to pass a List. 
Basically a functionality similar to using a Map.

Any pointers on how it can be done using Apache `HTTPClient` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kiyura for pointing me in the right direction, to make use of JSON.

I made use of the [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) java library for conversion from List to JSON representation.

Its a pretty library in case you want to use JSON without manually converting Generic Types.

The [gson doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) is also a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

The NameValuePair in this context is intended for sending simple text parameters as queries in the URL (the ?foo=1&bar=2 parameters you see sometimes). The best way to send something more complex like a list is to *serialize* it in an interchange format like XML or JSON and then send it as the request body.